# How can I replace my cursor with a circle instead of drawing it to canvas in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, rendering, p5.js

**The problem:** I'm trying to create a simple drawing app using p5.js. Instead of the standard cursor image, I'd like to show a circle at my cursor location that represents the size of the drawing brush.

**Potential solution 1:** Replace the cursor using the `cursor()` function native to p5.

**Why it doesn't work:** The [p5 cursor function](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/cursor) only takes the following parameters:

> ARROW, CROSS, HAND, MOVE, TEXT, or WAIT, or path for image

As such, there's no native way to replace the cursor using the ellipse class.

**Potential solution 2:** Use the `noCursor()` function and then draw the circle at the cursor location, while also drawing the background, as such:

```
var brushSize = 50;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1080,720);
  noCursor();
}


function draw() {
  background(100);
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,brushSize);

}
```

**Why it doesn't work:** While this solution gets the desired effect i.e. replacing the cursor with a circle the size of the brush, the constantly updating background prevents me from actually drawing to the canvas with the brush when I want to.

Is there some way I can replace the cursor without actually drawing the ellipse to the canvas? Is there any way to save and then instantly reload a canvas in p5? I couldn't find such a method searching through the API docs. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/cursor), you can pass a URL into the `cursor()` function to set an image.

If you want to use an image that you draw, you're going to have to draw them ahead of time and save them to files, and then use those files. Something like this:

```
cursor('images/ellipse-15.png');
```

Where `ellipse-15.png` is an image that you generated ahead of time, to match when `brushSize` is 15, for example.

Btw P5.js is just setting the cursor CSS property. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).

If you want to go with the `noCursor()` approach and draw the ellipse yourself, you could draw your drawing to a buffer (the `createGraphics()` function is your friend) and then draw the ellipse on top of that every frame. I'd still probably use a cross cursor just because there's going to be some annoying lag if you draw it yourself.

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks for the response! Do you know if there's any way to use `createGraphics()` to generate a circular buffer or will it always be a rectangular object blocking out a portion of the canvas?

Comment: Actually, I've thought of a different solution but run into another problem altogether. I've used `createGraphics()` to span the entire canvas, rendering the cursor ellipse on top of the new buffer and regenerating the background of the buffer. I'm trying to make the background transparent relative to the canvas, but I can only make it transparent relative to itself. Do you know of a workaround where I can recreate a transparent background thereby achieving the intended result?

Comment: @SkylarKennedy Please ask follow-up questions in their own posts. I don't understand what you mean by "transparent relative to itself". The buffer returned from `createGraphics()` is transparent by default.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I asked the follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710913/how-can-i-make-backgrounds-in-p5-js-transparent-but-continue-to-hide-elements-dr)

Answer (score 0):

Create a circular DIV inside the canvas container and show it on top of the actual canvas.

Comment: Welcome. Please expand your answer to contain more information and maybe code to show how this can be done. At the moment you run the risk of your answer being deleted as it is currently more like a comment. Please see [answer].