# How can I make backgrounds in p5.js transparent but continue to hide elements drawn on top of them?

Tags: javascript, canvas, rendering, p5.js

I'm asking this as a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49703094/how-can-i-replace-my-cursor-with-a-circle-instead-of-drawing-it-to-canvas-in-p5/49703181). I want to create a drawing app where the mouse is replaced by an ellipse that resizes to fit the brush size. The problem was that there was no way to draw the ellipse without leaving a mark on the canvas. The solution I came up with to solve this problem was to use `createGraphics()` as a buffer object and render the cursor on top of it as such:

```
var brushSize = 60;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1080,720);
  pg = createGraphics(1080, 720);
  background(100);
  noCursor();
}


function draw() {
  pg.background(0,0,0,0);
  pg.fill(255);
  pg.noStroke();
  pg.ellipse(mouseX/2,mouseY/2,brushSize);
  image(pg, 0, 0);

}

function mouseDragged() {
  noStroke();
  fill(255); 
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,brushSize);

}
```

In my solution, I'm using `createGraphics()` to span over the entire canvas, rendering its own background and then drawing an ellipse at the cursor location. In p5.js, `background()` takes a fourth parameter that describes its alpha channel. I thought this would give me my desired effect and create a transparent background on the buffer which allows full visibility of the canvas without actually drawing to it. However, if I set the fourth parameter in `pg.background()` to 0, the Graphics background doesn't render over the Graphics ellipse, which means the transparency is only relative to objects in the Graphics buffer.

I need some help in figuring out if there is any way to make the Graphics buffer transparent to the canvas and not to objects that render on the Graphics buffer itself. I know this explanation might be a little confusing so I drew up a little diagram to show what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're just looking for the `clear()` function. The `clear()` function makes a graphics object completely transparent. Use the `pg.clear()` function instead of the `pg.background()` function. You can find more info in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/clear).

But also note that what I meant in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49703181/873165) was that you could use the `createGraphics()` function to draw your painting to the buffer, and then draw the ellipse over top of that. Something like this:

```
function draw(){
  background(0);
  image(paintBuffer, 0, 0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, brushSize);
}

function mouseDragged(){
  paintBuffer.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, brushSize);
}
```

Comment: I checked out `pg.clear()` previously and it didn't seem to do anything different than setting background transparency to 0. However, I think I just didn't realize what you were proposing in your earlier solution. I never even thought about doing it the other way around, using the buffer to draw on and just using the canvas to display the cursor. That's way better than my solution man. Thanks so much! 10/10